# How to override the title tag for woocommerce endpoints?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, title, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am trying to set the title tag for Woocommerce pages that have endpoints. I am using Yoast SEO and so far have created this:

```
function woocommerce_endpoint_titles( $title ) {
    $sep = ' | ';
    $sitetitle = get_bloginfo();

    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) {
        $title = 'View Order'. $sep . $sitetitle;   
        return $title;
    }
    else if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) ) {
        $title = 'Edit Account'. $sep . $sitetitle; 
        return $title;
    }
    else if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ) {
        $title = 'Edit Address'. $sep . $sitetitle; 
        return $title;
    }
    else if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'lost-password' ) ) {
        $title = 'Lost Password'. $sep . $sitetitle;    
        return $title;
    }
    else if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'customer-logout' ) ) {
        $title = 'Logout'. $sep . $sitetitle;   
        return $title;
    }
    else if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) ) {
        $title = 'Order Payment'. $sep . $sitetitle;    
        return $title;
    }
    else if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        $title = 'Order Received'. $sep . $sitetitle;   
        return $title;
    }
    else if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'add-payment-method' ) ) {
        $title = 'Add Payment Method'. $sep . $sitetitle;   
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_title','woocommerce_endpoint_titles');
```

This works, but only for the endpoint pages, all other pages now don't have a title. How can I make my above code return the default title when not on an endpoint page?

Cheers,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to return the $title variable which already had what I needed:

```
function woocommerce_endpoint_titles( $title ) {
    $sep = ' | ';
    $sitetitle = get_bloginfo();

    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) {
        $title = 'View Order: ' . $sep . $sitetitle;    
    }
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) ) {
        $title = 'Edit Account'. $sep . $sitetitle; 
    }
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ) {
        $title = 'Edit Address'. $sep . $sitetitle; 
    }
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'lost-password' ) ) {
        $title = 'Lost Password'. $sep . $sitetitle;    
    }
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'customer-logout' ) ) {
        $title = 'Logout'. $sep . $sitetitle;   
    }
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) ) {
        $title = 'Order Payment'. $sep . $sitetitle;    
    }
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        $title = 'Order Received'. $sep . $sitetitle;   
    }
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'add-payment-method' ) ) {
        $title = 'Add Payment Method'. $sep . $sitetitle;   
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_title','woocommerce_endpoint_titles');
```

Answer (score 4):

If you added custom WC endpoints on init, you can use something like this instead to check for endpoints (adjust accordingly if you're using Yoast):

```
function add_custom_endpoints_to_title( $post_title ) {

    if ( ! is_account_page() ) {
        return $post_title;
    }

    global $wp;

    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['custom_endpoint_1'] ) ) {
        $post_title = 'Custom Endpoint 1';
    } elseif ( isset( $wp->query_vars['custom_endpoint_2'] ) ) {
        $post_title = 'Custom Endpoint 2';
    }

    return $post_title;
}

add_filter( 'single_post_title', 'add_custom_endpoints_to_title', 99 );
```

Comment: When matched, I'd advise to `remove_filter` to avoiding modifying other variables in the endpoint. See [WooCommerce Docs](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Customising-account-page-tabs#changing-an-endpoint-title)